# Access KeyVault from Azure Container Instance deployed in VNET

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-container-instances, vnet

Azure Container Instance is deployed in VNET and I want to store my keys and other sensitive variables in Key Vault and somehow access to it. I found in documentation, it's currently limitation to use managed identities once ACI is in VNET. 
Is there another way to bypass this identities and to use Key Vault?

I'm trying to avoid environment variables and secret volumes, because this container will be scheduled to run every day, which means there will be some script with access to all secrets and I don't want to expose them in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access the Azure Key Vault you will need to have access to a Token, are you ok storing this token into a k8s secret ?

If you are, then any SKD or CURL command could be use to leverage the Rest API of the Key Vault to retrieve the secret at run time : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/

If you don't want to use secret/volumes to store the token for AKV it would be best to bake in your token in your container Image and maybe rebuild your image everyday with a new token that you could manage its access I AKS at the same time within your CI process